# SIM800 MQTT publish to Google IoT Core

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mqtt, at-command, google-cloud-iot, sim800

I'm trying to publish some data to Google Cloud using the SIM800 module together with ESP32. Google IoT Core provides its documentation on connecting MQTT clients [here](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge#configuring_mqtt_clients). It says:

> Associate the MQTT client with MQTT server certificates.

However, in the SIM800 manufacturer's documentation on AT commands usage [(here)](https://microchip.ua/simcom/2G/Application%20Notes/SIM800%20Series_MQTT_Application%20Note_V1.03.pdf), there is nothing about associating the tls certificate. Given information concern making simple connections providing only the host, username and the password.

How can I make a connection that would take the certificate into account?